# AllowAny CreateAPIView returns 401 for unauthenticated users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I use DRF with `djangorestframework-simplejwt` package. In my **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    ...
]

...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTTokenUserAuthentication',
    ),
}

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
   'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
      'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header',
            'description': 'E.g. \'Bearer jwt.token.here\''
      }
   }
}
```

And in my apps' **views.py**:

```
...

class PublicCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Should be available for unauthenticated users
    """
    serializer_class = PublicThingSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response("It works!", 200)
...
```

Yet for some reason this view returns `401` response for unauthenticated users. I tried a lot of things, the best I got was noticing that when I remove the `REST_FRAMEWORK` config from my `settings.py` completely, the response code changes to `403 forbidden`. Any ideas?

Comment: clean your cookies and try again

Answer (score 5):

As [MojixCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11487872/mojixcoder) mentinoned in a comment, cleaning the cookies *might* have solved the issue but this time, after a few hours of debugging it turned out that my problem was actually related to `urls.py` which declared (simplified):

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("something/", views.SomethingViewSet()),

    ...

    path("something/more/", views.PublicCreateView.as_view())
]
```

And the issue was that while routing a request to url `/something/more/` Django actually used the first matching rule (perfectly understandable and expected behavior) which had `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated` set in `permission_classes`. This behavior is described in Django documentation on URL dispatcher under [How Django processes a request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) section, point 3:

> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and **stops at the first** one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.

Hope it saves someone's time. Since the API only returned a generic `401` answer that was surprisingly hard to figure out.